# Parameter passing in GSP

Tags: templates, grails, parameters, gsp

I'm having some troubles when getting some parameter in a GSP file.

Imagine a reddit-like site. There are subreddits, that in my case are "communities". I want users to be able to register in each community, and then post messages into it.

I have a "community" model and a "post" model. Each post belongs to a community. The page follows a common layout in all their pages (homepage, submit post page, etc). Some things are common in all pages, like the sidebars and navbar. Those common templates get a model [communityInstance: communityInstance] each time we call the **show** action in the community controller, so they can show the community name, number of users, etc. Until here, everything works OK.

Now, I want a submit post page, where the user can fill the title and body. This will be just a form. Let's say I just make a gsp file with a form (and all other common templates, via sitemesh) on it. I will link to it directly, no need to pass through a controller->action. How will my templates be able to get the data they need if I'm not calling community->show? Should I pass a parameter to the link with the community name, so the common templates could get it? I find cool and easy how actions can send parameters to gsp files, but what if I don't use an action?

Maybe I'm not explaining good enough, but I hope you get the idea.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
What if I have an action in community for each page I want? Should I have actions like "addPost", "viewPost", "editPost", etc in community that just render the views and pass them the data they need for the navbar/sidebar? Even with that, I would have to send parameters to the action everytime I want to render a page...

**Simpler:**
I have this structure /$community/addProp, where adProp is a gsp file (no action). How can I get the name of the community from the addProp.gsp file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if perfectly understand, but it seems you could just put the relevant community id in the submit form as a hidden input.

Comment: No, no, I didn't explain very well... The problem is that I need to render a template which uses data from a model. That model is passed to it via community->show, but when I just link to a static page (the form), I still need to use data from a model to populate the navbar and sidebars (name of the community, etc), and I'm not using community->show, just linking to communityName/addPost...

Comment: Would it work if you used a separate action to generate the form, which is generated via an ajax call and rendered with a partial template?